# godoc command not found

Tags: go, linux-mint, godoc

**godoc** command doesn't work on my system (I'using Linux Mint 20 Ulyana).

I've just tried this procedure:

1. install godoc with following command:

`go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc`

2. Start godoc server:

`godoc -http=:6060`

The result is:
`bash: godoc: command not found`

I'm using this go version `go version go1.15 linux/amd64`

And this is my PATH variable `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/go/bin`

All other go commands (go build, go run and so on) work correctly.

What can I do to make godoc command work?

Comment: Can you try `$GOPATH/bin/godoc -http=:6060` ?

Comment: Doing /home/myuser/go/bin/godoc -http=:6060 works.
But I think I need to execute godoc inside my project directory to expose to localhost:6060 the specific project documentation. Am I right?
Is there a way to execute commands without specifying absolute path?

Comment: See `go help install` for the directories where Go looks for binaries.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add `$GOPATH/bin` to your `PATH` variable. Executables, like `godoc`, are installed to `$GOPATH/bin`.

```
export PATH="$GOPATH/bin:$PATH"
godoc -http=:6060
```

Comment: If I'm not wrong, GOPATH is not used anymore.

So in $HOME/.profile I added a new line according your suggestion using $HOME instead of $GOPATH

```export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin```
```export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/go/bin```

And now it works! Thank you very much!

Comment: I had my `GOPATH=""`. So, I first had to set my GOPATH using `export GOPATH=/Users/myusername/go/`

Answer (score 26):

I have a different issue. As of 1.18, you must now run
`go install golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc`

This is because go get is deprecated for

> Starting in Go 1.17, installing executables with go get is deprecated. go install may be used instead. In Go 1.18, go get will no longer build packages...

In other words, `go get` in 1.18 and beyond will no longer install executables. Use `go install`.

Comment: good call on this change.

Answer (score 20):

### Step - 1: Check if godoc package is installed

Make sure you can run godoc using this command:

```sh
$GOPATH/bin/godoc -http=:6060
```

### Step - 2: Install godoc package

If you don't see any error then go to **Step - 4** else if you can see this error `No such file or directory` then you have to get the godoc package first by using this command:

```sh
go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc
```

It will take some time to install.

### Step - 3: Try godoc command

Try this command

```sh
godoc --help
```

if this command ran successfully then you are done and nothing else to do else if you are still getting any errors follow the **Step - 4** and if you still fail please check if you have defined the `$GOPATH` variable correctly

### Step - 4: Add path variable

Add $GOPATH/bin to your PATH variable by using this command:

```sh
export PATH="$GOPATH/bin:$PATH"
```

Try **Step - 3** now.

Answer (score 7):

I'm using macOS, for me `$GOPATH` was not configured and the path I found the installed package was `$HOME/go/bin/godoc`. Check out `go help gopath` for more information regarding this.

Comment: Plus-one for `go help gopath`, which led me to `go env GOPATH` to retrieve current `$GOPATH`!

Comment: For MacOS this is the only valid answer. Hours and hours lost for this unexpected behaviour of go tools

Answer (score 6):

Below is what I did on macos, it should work on linux as well.

Add this to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc`:

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/go # or somewhere else
export GOROOT=/usr/local/opt/go/libexec
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin
```

Reload your terminal and run:

```
mkdir -p $GOPATH $GOPATH/src $GOPATH/pkg $GOPATH/bin
go install golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc@latest
godoc -http=localhost:6060
```

Then you can open your browser at `localhost:6060` to RTFM ;-)

Answer (score 3):

`go install` installs the package under `$HOME/go/bin` (libraries are under `$HOME/go/pkg`)

`$GOPATH` is most likely empty if you install go manually without package managers,
add this after a successful go installation:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/go/bin/"
```

now every package you install with go install, will automatically be available gloabally

Answer (score 1):

From this
https://go.dev/ref/mod#go-install

Executables (main packages) are installed to the directory named by the GOBIN environment variable, which **DEFAULTS** to
#1. **$GOPATH/bin** or
#2. **$HOME/go/bin** if the **GOPATH** environment variable is not set.

In the case GOBIN is changed to a certain non-empty value, then the executable will be installed there, not in **$GOPATH/bin** any more.

As in my case, on Windows 11, I had changed the GOBIN to `D:\` and forget it. Then now, every time I run `go install`, the executable always created at the `D:\`.
This also causes some other files, such as `dlv.exe`, `goplay.exe`, ... appear at this `D:\` everytime I start the Visual Studio Code to edit a Golang source file.

After Googling around, my actions are:

- check what environment variables the `go install` uses by
  `go env`

then I detect that my GOBIN variable has the value of `D:\`

- reset the GOBIN variable by this command:
  `go env -u GOBIN`
- retry to use `go install`, e.g.
  `go install golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc@latest`

now the output, `godoc.exe`, is in the $GOPATH/bin as expected.

- I also tried to open Visual Studio Code to edit a Golang source file, these executables are now also created in the $GOPATH/bin, not in `D:\` anymore.
- I also tried to restart my PC, and found that this new GOBIN value is still, i.e. unset or empty value as by my last resetting action.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have macOS (Ventura, 14.2.1 (23C71)) and already installed `go`. I don't remember how exactly I have installed golang, but I truly believe that was via Homebrew (just `brew install go` command).

By default, the $GOPATH variable won't be settled in your shell config. My case was not special. Fortunately, when Homebrew will install `go` on your machine, check out `$HOME/go` dir and you will find the /go directory available with /bin and /pkg dirs in it.

That's what the go docs says as well, check out docs by the `go help gopath` command.

> If the environment variable is unset, GOPATH defaults
> to a subdirectory named "go" in the user's home directory
> ($HOME/go on Unix...

That means you can use `go install` command w/o any issues even if you don't set $GOPATH in your current shell.

The last step to install `godoc` on the macOS for me was finding the `godoc` package on pck.go.dev. The direct link: https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc.

The trick was to find out the *rigth* URL to copy and then use w/ `go install` command. Right now you can find the *Copy* button in the site's header. Works for any package available at the https://pkg.go.dev.

[image]

The result command is next:

```
go install golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc
```